# Jenkins - Downloading from Artifactory and Calculated MD5 checksum is different from original

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am working on a pipeline on Jenkins, in which a step is to download an artifact from Artifactory. It worked fine, but for one artifact, I receive a Calculated MD5 cheksum is different from original error. I've [seen a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490326/jenkins-groovy-jfrog-artifactory-getting-exception-while-downloading-artifac) with no real answer on that subject.

The important thing is as follows: Jenkins does download the artifact, but the zip file is 70MB larger than it is on Artifactory. If I download it manually using the link it echoes in the logs, I get the correct file.

My stage:

```
    stage("Download Artifact"){
    def server = Artifactory.server 'MYARTIFACTORYSERVER'

    def downloadSpec = """{
        "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "${sourcerepository}/${artifactpath}/${artifactname}/${artifactversion}${versionsuffix}/*${artifactidentifier}.zip",
                "target": "artifact-to-sign/"
            }
        ]
    }"""
    
    server.download(downloadSpec)
}
```

My logs:

```
Downloading artifacts using pattern: path/to/artifact/*.zip
Beginning to resolve Build Info published dependencies.
Downloading 'http://URL/artifactory/path/to/artifact/OBFUSCATED.zip'...
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Calculated MD5 checksum is different from original, Original: 'CHECKSUM1' Calculated: 'CHECKSUM2'
```

Any clue as to why the file size is different? **The content of the zip file seems identical in size. When unzipped, the checksum of the content is identical to Artifactory.**

When trying to unzip it, 7zip gives a warning: **There are some data after the end of the payload data**.

Comment: Having same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: @Deishelon Please check answer, I've solved the issue that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional testing has shown that the Artifactory download plugin corrupted downloads above 100MB, despite correct configuration of the Artifactory server. The reason behind this corruption, or whether it is a bug with the plugin or not, has not been established.

There's a way to avoid the issue by not using Artifactory to download the artifact in the first place. I do this by using curl.

```
curl http://URL/artifactory/path/to/artifact/OBFUSCATED.zip --output OBFUSCATED.zip
```

The plugin seems not to struggle for uploads over 100MB, and they work using the Artifactory plugin.